# How to fill/calculate motion_val in FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, video, vector, ffmpeg, motion-detection

I'm trying to get motion vectors of a mpeg video via ffmpeg (in c++).
The problem that I have is, that motion_val along with motion_subsample_log2 and mb_type of the AVFrame class remain empty and/or aren’t initialized (debugger says 0x0) and it seems that they are only available because of compatibility reasons
I’ve read in the [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors), that you can debug the motion vectors of the video via command line with

```
ffmpeg -vismv pf -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

The result is that the output.mp4 has motion vector arrows. So  I searched for the –vismv parameter in the code and found in libavcodec\options.c a long list of options:

```
{"vismv", "visualize motion vectors (MVs)", OFFSET(debug_mv), FF_OPT_TYPE_INT, DEFAULT, 0, INT_MAX, V|D, "debug_mv"},
```

I suppose that this line affects somehow debug_mv of AVCodecContext. With this assumption I searched for further information and I found some code snippets which I thought might help.

```
pAVCodecContext->debug_mv =  FF_DEBUG_VIS_MV_P_FOR | FF_DEBUG_VIS_MV_B_FOR | FF_DEBUG_MB_TYPE | FF_DEBUG_MV;
```

and

```
pAVCodecContext->debug |= FF_DEBUG_MV;
```

But both didn’t trigger the calculation or filling of the motion_val array. 
By the way my code is based on [the code by Victor Hsieh and Jiasi Chen](http://www.princeton.edu/~jiasic/cos435/motion_vector.c) and this code is basically the ffmpeg sourcecode (libavcodec\mpegvideo.c). I also tried to find (also with help of the documentation) the piece of code that triggers the calculation, but because of the complexity of the code I didn’t get any results.
The question  is now, if is there any possibility to fill this variables or start the calculation of the motion vector table or is there any other alternative way to get the motion vectors of every block of the mpeg-frames.

**Edit:**

<s>I forgot to mention my ffmpeg version</s>

Zeranoe's FFmpeg version: 2014-07-08 git-14e2406

- libavutil      52. 91.100 / 52. 91.100
- libavcodec     55. 68.102 / 55. 68.102
- libavformat    55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
- libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
- libavfilter     4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
- libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
- libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
- libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100

Changed to a newer version (2.5), but it didn't change/solve the problem.

Comment: You might be looking for the function `av_frame_get_side_data()` in `frame.c` and some of the code in `vf_codecview.c` related to the function `filter_frame`. The codecview filter is better suited for this purpose as `vismv` is deprecated. I have to update the wiki page at some point.

Comment: Also check `ff_print_debug_info2` in `mpegvideo.c`. There should be `motion_val` filled for every picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right. `av_frame_get_side_data()` was the method that helped. Also your hint with `vf_codecview.c` and `filter_frame` helped me a lot.

Comment: Great, I posted an official answer :) Feel free to edit it with the exact code you were using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motion vectors are available in the function `av_frame_get_side_data()` in the file `frame.c`.

Also, the `vf_codecview.c` file defines the filter that draws motion vectors—see the function `filter_frame()`.

For example, if you have an `AVFrame`, you can do:

```
AVFrameSideData *sd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
```

and from there:

```c
 if (sd) {
        int i;
        const AVMotionVector *mvs = (const AVMotionVector *)sd->data;
        for (i = 0; i < sd->size / sizeof(*mvs); i++) {
            const AVMotionVector *mv = &mvs[i];
            const int direction = mv->source > 0;
             // do something with motion vector
        }
    }
```